# Closed Set in Relative Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am pretty sure this result is true but I am feeling a little bit lazy trying to prove it rigorously (done way too many point-set proofs). Does anyone have a very short and elegant proof without too much chasing?

Let $X$ be a topological space, $C$ a closed subset and $A$ a subset. Then $A\setminus (A\cap C)$ is a closed subset of $(X\setminus C)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the standard topology, $C=[-1,1]$, and $A=(-2,2)$. Then $A\setminus(A\cap C) = (-2,-1)\cup(1,2)$, which is not closed in $\mathbb R\setminus [-1,1] = (-\infty,-1)\cup(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example. 

My original question was. Let $A$ be a quasi-affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $C$ a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$. I wanted to show that $A\setminus (A\cap C)$ is closed in $(\mathbb{A}^n \setminus C)$.

Comment: @ILoveMr.Paul: This should be posted in a different question, as the search feature does not allow to search in comments. You can close this question by accepting one of the answers, and post your other question afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion appears to be wrong.

Let $A$ be a set which is not closed, with $A\cap C=\emptyset$ then $A\setminus(A\cap C)=A$, which is obviously not a closed subset of $X\setminus C$.